# How to know if new element added to NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have a massive `array=["1","2","3","4","5","6"]`, with time.

For example: it would be `array=["1","2","3","4","5","6","10","11"]`.

How to know that  two elements added to massive? in the example, new elements added are 10 and 11.

Comment: it's really hard to understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
NSArray *array1 = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"];
NSArray *array2 = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"10",@"11"];
NSMutableArray *addedArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i < [array2 count]; i++)
{
    if (![array1 containsObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]]) {
        [addedArray addObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"New elements is added: %@", addedArray);
```

**Output:**

```
New elements is added: 
(
10,
11
)
```

Comment: `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` is faster.

Answer (score 2):

So basically you just need to remove the old elements and show the new elements.

You can try by using `removeOjbectsInArray` method of `NSMutableArray`

```
i.e.
NSArray *oldArray = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6"];
NSArray *newArray = @[@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"10",@"11"];
NSMutableArray *result = [newArray mutableCopy]; // make sure you make it a mutable copy
// remove the existing elements
[result removeObjectsInArray:oldArray];
NSLog(@"remaining entry: %@",result);
```

## Output

```
@[10,11];
```